# Methods declared in Application not accessible

Tags: java, android

Manifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:name="com.google.firebase.quickstart.database.App"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
</application>
```

My App.java:

```
public class App extends Application {
    protected List<Contact> main_contacts = null;
    public void setMainContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        main_contacts = contacts;
    }
    public List<Contact> getMainContacts() {
        return main_contacts ;
    }
}
```

My Activity.java:

```
public class MainActivity{
    @Override
    public void onContactsFetched(List<Contact> contacts) {
        getApplication().setMainContacts(contacts);//<= Not recognised
    }
}
```

Android Studio is not even recognising the mothods declared in `App`
[image]

Disc: omitted other methods above for brevity

Comment: Pretty sure you should cast the return object of getApplication() to App

Comment: Register your application in Android.manifest file and try to make your methods static.

Comment: @StarterPack thaks it works

Comment: @StarterPack can you move it to an answer, so that I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
public class App extends Application {
    protected List<Contact> main_contacts = null;
    public void setMainContacts(List<Contact> contacts) {
        main_contacts = contacts;
    }

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public List<Contact> getMainContacts() {
     return main_contacts ;
 }

 public static synchronized App getContext() {
    return mInstance;
 }
}
```

and you can access it like

```
App.getContext().yourMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast to your own App class, because the Android SDK method [`getApplication()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication()) does not know that you subclassed it.

```
public class MainActivity {
    @Override
    public void onContactsFetched(List<Contact> contacts) {
        // Cast to your App
        ((App)getApplication()).setMainContacts(contacts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the Application Object in Activity. After that you can access the Application class methods.

```
@Override
    public void onContactsFetched(List<Contact> contacts) {
        // Cast to your App
        MyAppication myAppication=(MyAppication) getApplication();
        myAppication.setMainContacts(contacts);
    }
```